# do i need to close the activemq connection if using pooledconnectionfactory

Tags: activemq-classic

i am using activemq PooledConnectionFactory to create connection. I am creating threads and each thread would have its own connection, session and producer.
I have two queries:
1. Do i need to close connection,session, producer myself in code or pooledConnectionFactory would do it once the message sending is successful by producer.
2. creating connection for every thread (eventually for each message) would be a performance bottleneck. Is it possible to have only one connection with many sessions in it (or there should be one-to-one mapping between session and connection, I think I read this somewhere on activemq website)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the code just as you would any other JMS Connection, Session, and Producer.  There's not magic to detect when your thread is done with it, you need to close it which will return it to the pool.  You can use only one Connection and take many sessions from it, but you need to close them so that they go back to the pool to be handed out to others on demand.

Comment: but when I closing session and connection, it complains(while running) that connection already closed. my code for sending message is in run method, accessed by more than one thread(each processing one message).I believe that each thread would have its own instance of connection and session, then why another thread running this code would complain for closed connection, if I close the connection at the end of code.